# How can I implement incr/decr on top of a key/value store?

Tags: key-value

How can I implement incr/decr on top of a key/value store?

I'm using a key value store that doesn't support incr and decr though which is why I want to create this. I have used Redis and Memcached incr and decr, so as mentioned in some of the answers then this is a perfect example of how I want the incr and decr to behave, so thanks to those who mentioned this.

Comment: What is your "key/value store"? What do you want to "incr/decr"?

Comment: @Webbisshh. Incr and decr in relation to key value stores means "atomic" increment and decrement. I'll try to find a link on the web as I'm not very good at explaining it

Comment: how will the value be used?  how much contention might there be on incr/decr?

Comment: @ron Alot of contention potentially.

Answer (score 1):

[Memcache](http://www.apachefriends.org/docs/phpdoc_de/function.memcache-increment.html) has this functionality [built in](http://www.apachefriends.org/docs/phpdoc_de/function.memcache-increment.html)

**edit:** it looks like you're not going to get an atomic update without updating the source, as there doesn't appear to be a lock function. If there is (and this is not pretty), you can lock the value, get it, increment it in your application, put it, and unlock it. Suboptimal though.

Comment: Thanks, I have amended the question

Answer (score 1):

The point of having a `incr()` function is it's all internal to the store. You don't have to pull data out and push it back in.

What you're doing sounds like you want to put some logic in your code that pulls the data out, increments it and pushes it back in... While it's not very hard (I think I've just described how you'd do it), it does defeat the point somewhat.

To get the benefit you'd need to change the source of your key store. Might be easy.

But a lot of caches already have this. If you really need this for speed, perhaps you should find an alternate store like memcached that does support it.

Answer (score 1):

it kind of seems like without a compareAndSet then you are out of luck.  But it will help to consider the problem from another angle.  For example, if you were implementing an atomic counter that shows the number of upvotes for a question, then one way would be to have a "table" per question and to put a +1 for each upvote and -1 for each downvote.  Then to "get" you would sum the "table".  For this to work I assume "tables" are inexpensive and you don't care how long "get" takes to compute, you only mentioned incr/decr.

Comment: I like this solution, and it seems like the most likely to work

Comment: although it wouldn't work if it had to retreive a unique counter

Comment: if you can say what other atomic operations are available we could probably piece it together.  is this an eventually consistent nosql key value store?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to atomically increment or decrement an `int` value associated with a key of e.g. type `string`, and if you'll know all of the keys in advance of having to perform the atomic operations on any of them, use `Dictionary<string, int[]>` and pre-populate the dictionary with a single-item array for each key value.  It will then be possible to perform atomic operations (e.g. increment) on items via code like `Threading.Interlocked.Increment(MyDict[keyString][0]);`.  If you need to be able to deal with keys that are not known in advance, you may need to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`, but you need to be careful if two threads try to simultaneously create dictionary entries for the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Since increment and decrement are simple addition and subtraction operations that are "commutative", what you need to implement is a PN-Counter. It is a CRDT (commutative replicated data type). Various examples of how to implement this on Riak are available around the web and on Github.